# PNG to JPG Java ImageIO problem

Tags: java, png, jpeg, javax.imageio

I have tried both lines of code below to no avail.  The code works fine with jpg, or gif but turns the image pink if a png.

```
ImageIO.write(input, "jpg", profileFile);

RenderedOp op = JAI.create("filestore", input, pFileName, "jpeg");
```

Anyone else run into this problem?  I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Is the PNG transparent?  Does it have an alpha channel?

Comment: It is not transparent.  I am not sure about the alpha channel.  This code is used when a user uploads photos on a website.  I convert all photos to JPG and would like to let them use PNG if they happen to have that.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicated your question. And there is answer about reported bug in Sun's library and workaround and link.

[Problem converting PNG to JPG using Java (ImageIO.write())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830063/problem-converting-png-to-jpg-using-java-imageio-write/1830086#1830086)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right answer or not. But there is [another post that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464825/converting-transparent-gif-png-to-jpeg-using-java) suggest that the implementation of JPEG writting with an alpha channel is a bit screwy.

Answer (score 0):

I draw PNGs with the following code and do not run into a problem.  It combines multiple PNG images into a single image.  The images have transparency, and use bilinear transform for blending.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
AffineTransformOp transformOp = new AffineTransformOp(new AffineTransform(), AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
g2d.drawImage(someOtherImage, transformOp, 0, 0);
```

When I finish the image, I write it to a response using the following code:

```
OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", responseStream);
```

Comment: This writes a png, the OP is trying to write a jpg/jpeg image.