# Issue using ImageIO.write jpg file: pink background

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm using the following code to write a jpg file:

```
String url="http://img01.taobaocdn.com/imgextra/i1/449400070/T2hbVwXj0XXXXXXXXX_!!449400070.jpg";
String to="D:/temp/result.jpg";
ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(new URL(url)),"jpg", new File(to));
```

But I get the `result.jpg` is a pink background image:

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate but a similiar result with `ImageIO.write()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830063/problem-converting-png-to-jpg-using-java-imageio-write

Comment: thanks,but `Page not found`,I can't get the answer

Comment: Which underlying reader do you use for reading jpeg with the ImageIO wrapper? It could be buggy.

Comment: I think it has something to do with a Transparency property. I had the same issue when I was trying to rotate an image. There was a transparency property that was set, once I removed it, all was well.

Comment: Possibly related to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pix/archive/2007/06/05/faq.aspx#q6.

Comment: This is likely the same bug as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340569/jpeg-image-with-wrong-colors and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474210/reading-jpegs-imageio-read-messes-up-color-space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPEG image with wrong colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340569/jpeg-image-with-wrong-colors)

Comment: This should be reopened. It includes the desired behavior (the image on the left), the specific problem or error (the image on the right), and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. It has a clear problem statement (summed up in a picture that doesn't require language, but also described above the image).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can work around this by using `Toolkit.createImage(url)` instead of `ImageIO.read(url)` which uses a different implementation of the decoding algorithm.

If you are using the JPEG encoder included with the Sun JDK then you must also ensure that you pass it an image with no alpha channel.

Example:

```
private static final int[] RGB_MASKS = {0xFF0000, 0xFF00, 0xFF};
private static final ColorModel RGB_OPAQUE =
    new DirectColorModel(32, RGB_MASKS[0], RGB_MASKS[1], RGB_MASKS[2]);

    // ...

String sUrl="http://img01.taobaocdn.com/imgextra/i1/449400070/T2hbVwXj0XXXXXXXXX_!!449400070.jpg";
URL url = new URL(sUrl);
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);

PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, -1, -1, true);
pg.grabPixels();
int width = pg.getWidth(), height = pg.getHeight();

DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferInt((int[]) pg.getPixels(), pg.getWidth() * pg.getHeight());
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, width, height, width, RGB_MASKS, null);
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(RGB_OPAQUE, raster, false, null);

String to = "D:/temp/result.jpg";
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File(to));
```

---

Note: My guess is that the color profile is corrupted, and `Toolkit.createImage()` ignores all color profiles.  If so then this will reduce the quality of JPEGs that have a correct color profile.

Answer (score 21):

I had similar problems. But then I solved it by using this one

```
   BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 

   //do something to populate the image
   //such as
   image.setRGB( x, y, pixelValue); //set your own pixels color



   ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("D:\\test.jpg"));
```

Note that I'm using Java version 1.6.0_25-b06
and It's just works fine.

Maybe you can check the Java version.

Comment: that totaly worked ! TYPE_INT_RGB is crucial here - this removes the pink hue - simply clone pixels from source ARGB image to the output RGB images and pink hue is gone !

Comment: Very similar answer to this one (though the code example on this one was easier to follow) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830063/problem-converting-png-to-jpg-using-java-imageio-write#answer-8418291

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

```
int w = originalImage.getWidth();
int h = originalImage.getHeight();
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] rgb = originalImage.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
newImage.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, rgb, 0, w);
```

Comment: Thanks for this more complete snippet. It works

Answer (score 2):

- for me the problem was not the reading but the writing
- ImageIO will happily write JPG files from ARGB BufferedImages
- Browsers/other programs then interpret this 4-channel file as CMYK color or something, resulting in the effect described in this question
- **solution** for me: make sure that that BufferedImage that is passed to ImageIO.write is of type RGB (not ARGB)
- this also explains why the problem only appears when saving to jpeg, but not when saving to png
- this took a long time for me to figure out because my own image tools always convert to ARGB on the fly, so I was always passing an ARGB image to ImageIO.write, without realizing it

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it complements with the working snippet provided in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(getContent());
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    for (int x = 0; x < originalImage.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < originalImage.getHeight(); y++) {
            newImage.setRGB(x, y, originalImage.getRGB(x, y));
        }
    }
```

this did the trick for me

Comment: tried this but did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when reading and writing images using `ImageIO`. After reading answers here I changed my JRE - from `openjdk version "1.8.0_91"` to `HotSpot java version "1.8.0_102"`. The hint was not obvious in `finnw`'s answer but it worth a try ;-)

And thus the issue resolved! So if you are using OpenJDK JRE and free to change your JRE, changing it HotSpot and you won't need to change your code.