# Create a buffered image from rgb pixel values

Tags: java, bufferedimage, pixel

I have an integer array of RGB pixels that looks something like:

```
pixels[0] = <rgb-value of pixel(0,0)>
pixels[1] = <rgb-value of pixel(1,0)>
pixels[2] = <rgb-value of pixel(2,0)>
pixels[3] = <rgb-value of pixel(0,1)>
...etc...
```

And I'm trying to create a BufferedImage from it. I tried the following:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
img.getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
```

But the resulting image has problems with the color bands. The image is unclear and there are diagonal and horizontal lines through it.

What is the proper way to initialize the image with the rgb values?

EDIT:
Here is what my image looks like[image]

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: setDataElements(...) works fine for me. Your int values must be wrong. Post your SSCCE demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @camickr, I think you are right and that my underlying pixel values may be wrong. I'll look into this a bit more and then post back.

Comment: This looks like bad data alignment. Your pixels are 32-bit ints, but an integer RBG format has only 24 bits. You should try creating a pixel struct with 3 bytes in it and passing an array of those over instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [int array to BufferedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416107/int-array-to-bufferedimage)

Answer (score 4):

Try `setDataElements` instead of `setPixels`.

Another option is for the image to share the array instead of copying from it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386446/problem-using-imageio-write-jpg-file/4388542#4388542) for an example.)

Comment: +1, cool, I learned the difference between setDataElements and setPixels.

Comment: I tried setDataElements, but I still get the same problem. I have added an image of what I'm seeing. Maybe it will give a hint into what might be causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it with a single array value. I believe you need three array values to specify the color when you use TYPE_INT_RGB:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageFromArray2 extends JFrame
{
    int width = 50;
    int height = 50;
    int imageSize = width * height;

    public ImageFromArray2()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( panel );
        int[] pixels = new int[imageSize * 3];

        //  Create Red Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize * 3; i += 3)
        {
            pixels[i] = 255;
            pixels[i+1] = 0;
            pixels[i+2] = 0;
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Green Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize * 3; i += 3)
        {
            pixels[i] = 0;
            pixels[i+1] = 255;
            pixels[i+2] = 0;
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Blue Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize * 3; i += 3)
        {
            pixels[i] = 0;
            pixels[i+1] = 0;
            pixels[i+2] = 255;
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Cyan Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize * 3; i += 3)
        {
            pixels[i] = 0;
            pixels[i+1] = 255;
            pixels[i+2] = 255;
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

    }

    private JLabel createImageLabel(int[] pixels)
    {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
        raster.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
        JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(image) );
        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new ImageFromArray2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: TYPE_INT_RGB uses a single int per pixel; OP specifies that each element of the int[] has an RGB value.

Comment: @MIchael Brewer-Davis, you would think that TYPE_INT_RGB uses a single int per pixel unit, however that does not appear to be the case when using the setPixel(...) method, which is why the question was asked. I provided a solution that shows how to use the setPixel(...) method. Having said that, the best answer is to use the setDataElements(...) method.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you cant get the correct image is that those pixels include the rgb colors, in order to set well each pix  you most do the next

```
double[] pixelsArr=new double[4];
pixelsArr[0]=(Integer.parseInt(string2.trim())>>16) & 0xFF;
pixelsArr[1]=(Integer.parseInt(string2.trim())>>8) & 0xFF;
pixelsArr[2]=(Integer.parseInt(string2.trim())) & 0xFF;
pixelsArr[3]=0xFF;
img.getRaster().setPixels(col,row,1,1, pixelsArr);
```

string2 is an integer pixel     col is the position of each pix and row the same, and 1,1 is the size of each pixel.