# Use android.graphics.Bitmap from Java without Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I need to use android.graphics.Bitmap in my Java project without Android platform. The problem is that I want to process the picture which comes to the server from Android device as a Bitmap.
So, I need some methods that use native code. How can I get these native methods? I tried to find them at http://androidxref.com but if I have, for example,

`static int Bitmap_width(JNIEnv* env, jobject, SkBitmap* bitmap) {return bitmap->width();}`

clicking `width()` refers to the new search where there are lots of classes contating different `width()`.

Comment: Do you mind me asking *why* you need to use `android.graphics.Bitmap`? There are plenty of available Java-native bitmap libraries. You don't need to use the Android one just because it came from Android. A bitmap is a bitmap, as long as it's sent in some recognizable format(jpg, png, simple byte array, etc).

Comment: I tried `java.awt.BufferedImage` but haven't succeeded in making it work. I'm not so familiar with it. Probably, you have some suggestions concerning the proper libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this. Now the server gets only width, height of the image and array of pixels derived by `bitmap.getPixels(...)` on the device and builds the picture as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617845/create-a-buffered-image-from-rgb-pixel-values)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. The android libraries are not meant to be used for non android applications. Especially the native code.

As long as you send a bitmap image, any non-android library will be able to read it.

You can event send the image raw pixels. It's like sending a list of bytes. Any language will be able to read incomming bytes.

Comment: Have you got any references to the papers on the topic?