# Constructing an Image using RGB values

Tags: java, image-processing

I am having RGB values of each pixel of an Image. Now I want to reconstruct the image using these values. How do I achieve it using java?

Comment: You utilize a graphics library. If you ask which graphics library you should use, this will become opinion based.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a buffered image from rgb pixel values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617845/create-a-buffered-image-from-rgb-pixel-values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [int array to BufferedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416107/int-array-to-bufferedimage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's hardly much more to say than this...

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for (int x=0; x<w; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<h; y++)
    {
        image.setRGB(x,y,rgbValueFor(x,y));
    }
}
```

... and that you don't seem to have searched the Web or so...