# Reading JPEGs: ImageIO.read() messes up color space

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio

I'm trying to read, rescale and save images within a Servlet. That's the relevant code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(factor, factor);
AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
after = scaleOp.filter(image, null);

ImageIO.write(after, "JPG", file));
```

The original file is a plain RGB-Jpeg, but when I open and save the file it comes out as a CMYK-Jpeg. That happens even if i don't rescale the image, just opening and closing the image causes the problem.

When I open PNGs or GIFs everything is fine. Does anybody know what to do here? I would expect ImageIO's read-Method to retain the original colorspace.

If there's another way comfortable way of reading jpeg's?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You create `after` and then overwrite it with `scaleOp.filter`. Is this correct? So your `after` image may not be RGB even though you think it is? If you want `after` to be RGB then you may need to 'draw' `image` onto `after` *before* you do the transform.

Comment: That's a good hint: the filter method returns a completely new BufferedImage. So now I know, the Image doesn't get "colored" when it is read, but upon my transformation. I tried to draw the original image onto the destination image using `graphics.drawImage(image, scaleOp, 0, 0)`, now it gets transformed correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it's working! I'll add as an answer so the qn can be closed.

Comment: I'm still wondering, why the filter-Method didn't work correctly,  though... or if i could have made the filter method work correctly...

Comment: Yes, maybe if you did `scapeOp.filter(image, after)`, it would use the `after` image you created with the RGB type. If `null` is used, maybe the method is free to create an image with the colour space of its choice.

Comment: That's what the API says, more or less. But when I pass in `after` as the second Param, I get an `ImagingOpException`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create `after` and then overwrite it with `scaleOp.filter`. Is this correct? So your `after` image may not be RGB even though you think it is? If you want `after` to be RGB then you may need to 'draw' `image` onto `after` before you do the transform.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, and found this page.

I tried the suggestion above of creating a BufferedImage with the right type and using it as the after image instead of null in the filter call; and that did indeed resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageIO.read` ignores all embedded metadata, including an embedded color profile, which defines how RBG values map to physical devices such as screens or printers.

You could read the metadata separately and pass it to `ImageIO.write`, but it's easier to just convert the image to the (default) sRGB color space and ignore the metadata.

If you don't mind losing the metadata, replace

```
after = scaleOp.filter(image, null);
```

with

```
after = scaleOp.filter(image, after);
```

From the documentation of [`AffineTransformOp.filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html#filter%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage%29):

`If the color models for the two images do not match, a color conversion 
into the destination color model is performed.`