# ImageIO jpg the image becomes pink after resizeImage

Tags: java, image, swing, image-processing, javax.imageio

```
public static void main(String argsp[]){

    File src = new File("C:\\Users\\chang\\Desktop\\shinichi_hoshi-2011-hp.jpg");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(fis);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\chang\\Desktop\\www1.jpg");
        BufferedImage bsi = ImageUtil.resizeImage(bi,100,100,true,0);

        ImageIO.write(bsi, "jpg", fos);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6075213/571816

Comment: ImageIO in javax.imageio.ImageIO

Comment: @Peter ImageIO does not offer resize/rescale feature. What is ImageUtil.resizeImage? Are you using `Image.getScaledInstance(width, height, hints)`?

Comment: resizeImage(BufferedImage orig, int width, int height, boolean shrinkOnly, int resizeMode) in org.saladn.web.util.ImageUtil

Answer (score 2):

The problem must lie in your `resizeImage` method. I have no issue with your code:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestImageResize {

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestImageResize.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://noupe.com/img/wallpaper-4.jpg"));
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "test.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Image image = bi.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        BufferedImage bsi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        bsi.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        ImageIO.write(bsi, "jpg", fos);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestImageResize().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Result scaled image displayed in JFrame:
[image: Result scaled image]

Result scaled image (displayed by your browser):
[image: Result image uploaded from disk]

Original image:
[image: Original image]

Comment: Try google test of the main picture to jpg file

Comment: @Peter I am puzzled as to how you get a pink image while my screenshots obviously proves the contrary. What do you mean by "Try google ...", give me a straight link if you want to show me something.

Comment: @Peter If you are getting a pink effect, it is likely because you use a BufferedImage with an alpha-channel while JPG does not support that. Make sure you use a `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` and not `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`

Comment: sorry, If you upload image with main image of Google, it will come out in pink color.
Other images don't have an issue.
Just main image of Google is an issue.
Please test it after downloading directly.
And it still shows pink color although I have tested in two ways - BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB and  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB.

Comment: @Peter Do you mean Google main logo? Just provide exact links instead of using words, it would be a lot simpler. I tried one of the logos of Google and it did not cause any issue. Maybe there is some issues with your implementation of ImageIO. What JVM are you using?

Comment: sorry, I can not English, My JVM is java version 1.7.0_02 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: @Peter Then I don't understand your problem. I have absolutely no issues executing my code with that same JVM. Edit my code to reproduce your issue and then edit your post by adding your edited code.

Comment: that is My sourcecode. same source of Guillaume Polet. but my sourcecode have pink color

Comment: File filePath = new File("C:\\Users\\chang\\Desktop\\05036877.jpg");
   com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageDecoder jpegDecoder =  JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder (new FileInputStream(filePath));
   BufferedImage image = jpegDecoder.decodeAsBufferedImage();    -> no problem, thank you Guillaume Polet^^

Answer (score 0):

public class ImageTest {

```
public static void main(String argsp[]) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new ImageTest().initUI();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame(ImageTest.class.getSimpleName());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new URL(
            "http://www.google.co.kr/logos/2012/field_hockey-2012-hp.jpg"));
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "test1.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Image image = bi.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    BufferedImage bsi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null),
            image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    bsi.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", fos);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    panel.add(label);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: that is My sourcecode.   same source of Guillaume Polet. but my sourcecode have pink color

Answer (score 0):

This answer looks pretty much what you are looking for (even though I didn't test it myself):

[Unable to read JPEG image using ImageIO.read(File file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file)