# Image Conversion In Java

Tags: java, image

I've designed a rest service to respond the images stored in the database for the users. The service works fine. The service responds the images in jpg format. If the user uploads the image in the jpg format the the response is also fine, if the image is some other formats, then the response cannot be rendered as image. I need to construct a jpg converter or encoder, for all the input image types. Is there are any possible way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, there is a possible way. What have you tried?

Comment: Where are you trying to render the image? Does the service return the image fine? is there any error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should take a look at `ImageIO`.  It has support for reading and writing JPEG, PNG, BMP, WBMP and GIF.

The JAI API also supplies TIFF support and I've used a RAW plugin for Nikon cameras before as well.

Check out [Working with Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) and the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) for more info.

**Updated with Example**

Without the source image is not going to be possible to do a proper test, but this is the basic work flow.

I've used `File` as my inputs, but to demonstrate the basic concept, I've create `InputStream` and `OutputStream` (as `ImageIO` can read/write `File`s)

```
File inputFile = new File("/path/to/image.png");
File outputFile = new File("Test.jpg");
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Updated**

So using the above code, I was able to convert a PNG file I created in paint to JPG...

**PNG/JPG**

[image][image]

You could also try converting the input stream and output stream to an `ImageInputStream` and `ImageOutputStream`, although this is normally done when you want to look up the providers for a given image format.

```
File inputFile = new File("...");
File outputFile = new File("Test.jpg");
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(iis);
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", ios);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer, I tried with the ImageIO. I have read the input stream and created a bufferedImage, and created the desired format. The input file is PNG and the output file JPG. The input file has a black line with white backgroud and output file produced contains the line with Orange Background.

Comment: Thanks for the Update  MadProgrammer. But the same code when we use the png image created from ms paint doesn't work. Even I use the same snippet.

Comment: I've tested it using a PNG created using MS Paint without issue.  Try an isolated/standalone test first and see if makes any difference, it is possible that the `InputStream` could be getting corrupted...It might require you to fully upload the file first and THEN convert it

Comment: +1 great example + screens. @wekselva see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551646/convert-a-jpanel-to-an-image-in-a-jscrollpane/14551679#14551679) alternate approach (scroll to bottom of answer)