# how to convert JPEG image to TIFF image?

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio

I am developing an app for image processing for that I need to convert JPEG file to TIFF file.

I have tried below code snippet for conversion. But, it is generating corrupt tiff file.

Here is the code:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.idrsolutions.image.tiff.TiffEncoder;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class JavaApplication2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage;
        try 
        {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Jay Tanna\\Desktop\\image1.jpg"));


            BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(),
            bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            newBufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);

            OutputStream   out      =   new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Jay Tanna\\Desktop\\myNew_File.tiff");
            TiffEncoder tiffEncoder =   new TiffEncoder();
            tiffEncoder.setCompressed(true);
            tiffEncoder.write(newBufferedImage, out);

            System.out.println("Done");

    } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }

}
```

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image Conversion In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618953/image-conversion-in-java)

Comment: imageIo does not support tiff file format and tiff is hard requriment@MaximDobryakov

Comment: @MaximDobryakov

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading and Writing out TIFF image in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898311/reading-and-writing-out-tiff-image-in-java)

Comment: @JayTanna You could try using standard ImageIO and my [ImageIO TIFF plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#tiff---aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with `com.idrsolutions.image.tiff.TiffEncoder`, but you're definitely missing a `out.close()` without which some data may remain buffered and not make it to disk.

Comment: ...or better yet, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) when creating `out`.

Answer (score -1):

Change the extension of the file, try this:

```
OutputStream   out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Jay Tanna\\Desktop\\myNew_File.tiff");
```

for this:

```
OutputStream   out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Jay Tanna\\Desktop\\myNew_File.TIF");
```