# How to edit the format of Image in Java?

Tags: java, image, format

I have a form to upload image, so what I want is that whenever a user uploads any type of image (png/jpg etc) convert that image into jpg and save that image to storage from Multipart.

Comment: See here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/convert-png-to-jpeg-image-file-in-java/

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290336/converting-png-into-jpeg

Comment: I am uploading a file that is In MultipartFile format , I want to first change it into jpg format and than save it into storage .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [First Google hit](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/). Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a response with this previous question :

[Image conversion in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14619218/10744028v)

```
File inputFile = new File("/fileOfYourForm.png");
File outputFile = new File("NewImage.jpg");
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```