# Is it possible to convert hidden jpanel into image in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to convert jpanel into image file which is not currently active(ie, that jpanel is hidden).

Please guide me how to do that? Is there any possible?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551646/convert-a-jpanel-to-an-image-in-a-jscrollpane/14552324#14552324 may be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

- you can to create `BufferedImage` from any of `JComponents` that returns `Dimension`

.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage ((int)panel.getSize().getWidth(),
             (int)panel.getSize().getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

- then is possible to change its properties too, more in [2D Graphics trail Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply. But this is working for currently active panel. I have asked about hidden panel?

Comment: [returns Dimension, for example(@David Kroukamp)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14551679/714968)