# Bizarre image corruption from resized JPEG with embedded 'c2' colorspace

Tags: java, image, image-processing, jpeg, javax.imageio

I'm using java ImageIO plus the [TwelveMonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) library to generate square thumbnails of various images. This works pretty well, but in some rare percentage of cases, the thumbnail images get corrupted in a really bizarre way, for example:

original:

[image: original]

resized and corrupted:

[image: corrupted]

Even more bizarre is that the bug seems transient; regenerating the thumbnail using the same code and environment works fine. Thus, my main question is:

**How exactly are the pixels of the corrupted image mapped from the original?**

The corrupted image doesn't match any of the image operations I know; low-frequency features in the original seem to have been mapped to high-frequency patterns in the corrupted, yet some high-frequency features like the text are retained in the corrupted image.

**Update:** here are the RGB channels decomposed, which are perhaps more telling:

[image: red]

[image: green]

[image: blue]

All three channels are almost (but not quite) completely saturated, and only the green channel retains spatial details. There's a patch of black in the original (left of the shield) that's reflected in the red channel though

Other details of note:

- The original image has an embedded 'c2' color profile, [a.k.a. the facebook profile](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150630639853920), and only these 'c2' images have resulted in this kind of corruption. However, the corruption isn't a simple color remapping ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386446/problem-using-imageio-write-jpg-file?lq=1)) which usually results from ignoring the color profile. Also, I've resized plenty of other 'c2' images without problems.
- I'm using the [ResampleOp operation of TwelveMonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#using-the-resampleop), `ResampleOp.FILTER_TRIANGLE`, which calls [AffineTransformOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html) under the hood. [The implementation](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/94ed531fb284d824e6edbd40b3eb406366fe790f/common/common-image/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/ResampleOp.java#L668) doesn't appear to do anything non-deterministic, but then again, imageIO seems to do a lot of magic in off-heap native code.

Comment: Are you saying this happens sometimes but not always? Bizarre indeed... I'll look into it one day! In the mean time, what Java version are you using and on what platform? Also if you have a full MVCE to reproduce the issue that would help a lot.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great library. I'm using oracle JDK `1.8.0_25-b17`, on linux hotspot `build 25.25-b02`, but I have yet to reproduce the corruption on-demand, even using identical code and input. I'm hoping that figuring down how the image is actually corrupted will lead me to the actual resolution. It could be something totally unrelated like part of the PNG format getting truncated in network transfer, or something else suitably transient and hard to reproduce.

Comment: I have my suspects... ;-) Can you try using `-Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider` to see if that helps? Not sure if it works on Linux, but it does in other environments (Windows/OS X). The switch from the old but trusty Kodak CMS to LCMS has caused a few headaches for me...

Comment: PS: The resulting image seems to have (almost) only primary colors (all R, G, B either 0 or 255)... I've seen images like this as a result of integer overflow, but it's hard to say exactly what computation has produced this image.